# Trying to increase unlock time of camunda if due to wrong username password it has been locked

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, camunda-plugin

To increase unlock time of camunda ,please suggest some property given by camunda.i tried with loginDelayMaxTime property but it did not worked .please suggest.In xml file adding a property loginDelayMaxTime and giving value as 60000.but not working

I want that if camunda is getting locked it should unlocked after 10 min or whatever time i set it should unlock after that because by default it is unlocking in only 1 min.